# No sound on my Toshiba Satellite. Was working this morning

Tags: audio, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite A305 and the sound suddenly stopped working.

I've checked on sound volume and it's up to max. I've also checked devices and it says it should be working fine.

Sound was working 100% fine 2 hours ago and now it's not working. I haven't installed/uninstalled anything during this time so that isn't the issue.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: You're not on mute per chance?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you got a headphone plugged into your Laptop?

Comment: You could try booting up knopix, a live boot linux distrabution and see if sound works there.  If it does then you have a software problem.  If it doesn't then you probably have a hardware problem.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but also try rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the external volume dial? They are hard to find on some laptops. I had a similar problem and I was not aware my laptop had a hardware volume dial as well a software setting.

Answer (score 0):

See may be the driver has been crash. so just re install the sound driver.
If by doing this your laptop still has no sound try plunging a speaker or headset. If you can't just bring it to the support center.